# What does PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials return true for blank passwords?

Tags: c#

We have a login box for our app that asks the user to enter their AD credentials. We take those credentials and then call

```
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, container, ContextOptions.SimpleBind))
    {
        return pc.ValidateCredentials(domain + @"\" + username, password, ContextOptions.SimpleBind);
    }
```

to validate that they've entered a valid login/password pair. What we found out though, was that the call to ValidateCredentials will return true with a blank password, and we have no idea why. An invalid password returns false, but blank will return true as long as the username is correct.

Comment: Are you by chance logging on as the same user (e.g. username) as the user that's currently logged on to the machine doing the testing (i.e. you're logged into the machine as `domain\user1` and you're logging into the application as `domain\user1`)?

Comment: I wonder if this is a similar issue to what I saw with it returning true for unknown users? Eventually found the answer - related to the guest account being enabled. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7336610/130352 for the full details.

Comment: @ChrisJ Nope, we have the problem with one of our customer and the guest account is disabled. Still trying to figure out why a blank password is accepted.

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889.aspx

> The ValidateCredentials method binds to the server specified in the constructor. If the username and password parameters are null, the credentials specified in the constructor are validated. If no credential were specified in the constructor, and the username and password parameters are null, this method validates the default credentials for the current principal.

In the PrincipalContext constructor you could specify the credentials you want to check as well.

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, 
                       container, ContextOptions.SimpleBind, username, password))
{
    return pc.ValidateCredentials(domain + @"\" + username, password,
                                   ContextOptions.SimpleBind);
}
```

Comment: In the PrincipalContext constructor you connect to the LDAP server using the username and password. Why would you THEN, after that, validate the credentials? This is redundant, right?